# Windows Phone 7: How can I pass multiple query string parameters to default NavigationPage in WMAppManifest.xml file?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to pass multiple values to my default page using query string in the NavigationPage of Windows Phone 7. I am passing in the same way as we pass querystring using NavigationService but this is not working when I pass in WMAppManifest.xml.

```
WMAppManifest.xml: 
 <Tasks>      
  <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="Page.xaml?param1=val1&param2=val2"/>      
 </Tasks>
```

Please tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you geting val1 and val2 from?

Comment: Yeah - I don't get it... What about this could possibly be useful?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're editing an XML file and the ampersand is a special character within XML you'll need to escape the string for this to work.
Like this:

```
<DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="Page.xaml?param1=val1&amp;param2=val2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In code it's like this way:

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WedstrijdUitslag.xaml?param1=" + value2+ "&param2=" + value1, UriKind.Relative));